# Get todays records from SQL using C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, datetime, comparison

Within a DB I have a table that has  afield named Data Recolha, I checked its data type and it's datetime.
The valued stored is as follows: **26/08/2019 5:00:00**

```
string hoje = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy H:mm:ss.fff");

string query = "SELECT * FROM  database WHERE  CodCliente=1 AND 'Data Recolha' >= '" + hoje + "'" ;
```

I've also tried converting to date, used cast on both values, I either get an error or when I run the code it displays all values stored in the table. Also used different used *hoje* as DateTime as string with and without format.
The values are stored in a C# DataTable and I checked the type of the value gathered from field *Data Recolha* and it's stored as System.DateTime.

Comment: Try using [Data Recolha] >= ...

Comment: To get all of the `DateTime` values on a given date you need to use something like `... where @GivenDate <= [Date Recolha] and [Date Recolha] < DateAdd( day, 1, @GivenDate )` where `@GivenDate` is a `Date` (or `DateTime` with a zero time). That way all of the times on the date are included in the interval (`<=`), but the subsequent date is not (`<`). SQL Server will Do The Right Thing℠ when comparing `Date` and `DateTime` values. You should use _parameterized queries_ to avoid data type and SQL injection issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What your code does is string comparison because:
 
`'Data Recolha'` is **not** the name of the column `Data Recolha` since you enclosed it in single quotes, and
`hoje` is a string literal.
 
So enclose `Data Recolha` in square brackets and convert `hoje` to `datetime` with [`CONVERT()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) like this:

```
[Data Recolha] >=  convert(datetime, hoje, 103)
```

So use this:

```
string query = "SELECT * FROM  database WHERE  CodCliente=1 AND [Data Recolha] >= convert(datetime, '" + hoje +"', 103)";
```

Answer (score 1):

1. please using sqlparameter not `string concat` to avoid sqlinjection
2. if you're using DataReader or DataTable to read data,i'll recommend you to use [Dapper](https://github.com/StackExchange/Dapper) to simplify code.

```
using(var connection = yourconnection)
{
    datetime hoje = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
    string sql = "SELECT * FROM  database WHERE  CodCliente=1 AND 'Data Recolha' >= @hoje" ;
    var result = connection.Query(sql,new{hoje});
}
```